# Long or short form?

Tags: structure

Sometimes, when I write my stories, I may include a very long sentence but it can be desrcibe eith a short sentence.

i.e: What I write: " When I went into the room of darkness, the light that surrounded fade away in lighting speed. I laid down like a falling feather into my comfy place, and opened the door of dreams."

What it mean: "I was going to sleep."

Is it ok to write like this? Because some of friends think it's boring and some of them can't understand it.

Comment: For whom are you writing?  Where will it be published?  Knowing the conventions of the space you're trying to fit into is important.  Without knowing more about what you're trying to do, this seems like it's just an opinion poll, which isn't a good fit for this site.  I'm putting this on hold for now; please check out our short [tour] and then [edit] this to fit better with our site guidelines.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the sentence. It's a little flowery, but if that's your style, as long as the reader understands what you intend, it's fine. Your friends may have different tastes in prose and prefer short, crisp descriptions instead. Nothing wrong with that either.

Answer (score 0):

What language do you write in? Because if you write in English, I must admit that your typing errors and grammar mistakes make it hard for me to understand your sentences.

If you write in your mother tongue, your use of imagery obfuscates your meaning. For example, what is the "door of dreams"? It could be a door to an alternate universe in a fantasy story. Or a metaphor for taking a psychoactive drug. Or, what is "the room of darkness"? Without your translation given below your example, I wouldn't have thought of a dark room, but of the den of some Lovecraftian horror.

I think it is okay to use metaphors and imagery, but you should be aware of how certain phrases are commonly used and the ideas that they commonly evoke, so your readers have an actual chance of understanding you.

Also, in prose, too many metaphors tend to become tiresome to the average reader. They are okay in poetry, but in prose narrative they are deviations from standard language and should be used with restraint.

Comment: English is my second language, so I am not really good on writing in English.

Comment: Yes, but do you write your *stories* in English? No one expects you to write perfect English in an internet forum, but if you want to write literary texts, mistakes are an obstacle to understaning.